# When should multiple controllers be used in the same page in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I would like to know when does it make sense to use multiple controllers on the same page in angularjs. Also, when should one think about separating a controller into multiple controllers?

Answer (score 0):

You should largely have your functionality in providers (services or factories typically) and your controllers should have very little in them aside from getting the providers injected (and exposing models and functions for use in the view) and possibly some view specific functionality (configuration for directives used only in one place etc.).  You can have multiple controllers on the page if you decide to build the views within a page to be portable.

If you have one controller that shares the functionality needed for disparate parts of a page and later decide to move one part of the view to another route/state/view then you'll need to piece apart the controller.  I don't think there are any hard rules really but if your controller is more than 100 lines you're probably making it responsible for too much and should "promote" some things to be handled by providers and/or start splitting things up a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be dependent on your page requirement. Having multiple controllers can easily be done.. But issues pop-up when you wanted to have page flows.

Controllers are just a part of AngularJS.. Usage of services, factories and filters is a recommended way of splitting your code along with controllers. If multiple controllers per page becomes imperative.. try utilizing directives. Also consider using Views  provider by UI router.

Comment: I am not asking if multiple controllers can be used per page. I am asking when will it be suitable or required to use multiple controllers on one page.

Answer (score 0):

I use multiple controllers when my page has got multiple pop-ups with complex functionality and i want separate controllers for them so that logic behind each-pop is in its own controller.

Similarly, I create separate controllers for sidebars and header and footers on the same page.
These are few examples which comes in my mind when using multiple controllers on same page makes sense.

But as others have mentioned, you should use providers and services/factory for splitting your code.